# How to prevent switching tabs using horizontal mouse scroll in Mac Chrome 75?

Tags: google-chrome, macos-mojave

In macOS 10.14.5, I installed Google Chrome 75. When I am using the Apple MagicMouse (Model A1296), the horizontal mouse scrolling (when hovering on tab bar) is too sensitive, making the Chrome switching tabs rapidly.

Is there any way I can stop this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=965753#c61) the Chromium development team fixed the issue in late August 2019 and it was included in Release 77 of Chrome. I just updated from 75.x and can confirm the issue is now resolved.